# Server / Client message passing in C

Tags: c, linux, client, file-descriptor

I've developed a client that connects to a server. The client writes something to the server and the server reads and responds back to the client. The client then reads what the server said and both terminate. I wish to extend this allowing the client and server to continue talking for say 3 more time and then terminate. I produced a for loop where inside this loop I handled the code read and write code on both of the server and client, but it is ending up in an infinite loop and writing the text inputted in the first time rather than re asking the user to enter new data.

The server code where the read/write is handled is as follows:

```
int temp = 0;
char cha [10] = "helloworld";
while(temp = 3){

int rc;
char ch[100];


rc = read(newsockfd, &ch, 100);
    printf("Client sent: %s\n", ch ) ;      

    write(newsockfd, cha + temp, 100);

temp ++;
}


close(sockfd);
close(newsockfd);
```

This is the client code where read/write is handled:

```
int temp = 0;
char cha[10] = "abcdefhijk";

while(temp = 3)       
{
int rc;
char ch2 [100];

rc = write(sockfd, cha + temp, 100);

    read(sockfd, &ch2, 100);
    printf("Server said: %s\n", ch2);

temp ++;
}


sleep(2);
close(sockfd);
```

Also, I am closing the file descriptors after loop is completed.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `while(temp = 3)` looks like a typo. suggestion: use a for() loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you provide the loop code also? And are you using blocking or non-blocking calls to read() and write()? (that is, do they return immediately independently of whether data is available (non-blocking), or do they block until something is available (blocking))?

Update:
If the code you posted is the actual code, then your while loop is at fault. You check for

```
temp = 3
```

Which is always true, as you are just assigning '3' to temp. You probably mean

```
temp < 3
```

?

Comment: i am not sure if the read and write are blocking or non-blocking, but from what I can say is that in the first loop, the server waits for the client to send him something, which hence i am presuming its blocking... but again , i am not sure...  i am going to update to code above including the loop..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put all your queries to the Questioner in the comments section and not in answers.

Comment: Pavan, I'd love to do that, but sadly I don't yet have enough reputation to be able to... Commenting on other peoples questions apparently requires at least a rep of 50...

Comment: @sonicwave thanks a million mate ! that was it.. very silly of me.. thanks! :)

Comment: @sonicwave: You should have waited until you have 50 reputation (which you now do) before you start to post comments. The restriction is there for a reason. In any case, since you've made it an answer and it's now accepted, I don't have to convert this post anymore so I'll leave it as it is.